# What is the difference between '/path/to/file/' , '/path/to/file/.' and '/path/to/file' in Linux specifically RHEL and RHEL like distributions?

Tags: linux, rhel

In RHEL 9,

1. The command `cp -a /somedir/. .` executes to copy all files in 'somedir' directory (not the directory itself) to the current directory.
2. The command `mv /somedir/. .` though yields the error 'cannot move: Device or Resource busy'.
3. The commands `mv /somedir/ .` and `mv /somedir .` result in moving directory 'somedir' to the present directory.

**Questions;**

1. Why does the second command result in an error?
2. Without the use of `*` is there a way to move only the contents of directory `somedir` and not the directory itself to the current directory using `mv` command?
3. What is the difference between `/path/to/file/` , `/path/to/file/.` and `/path/to/file` in Linux specifically RHEL and RHEL like distributions?

Comment: also consider `rsync` behavior that is specific in those cases

Answer (score 0):

The path ending in `/` is the same as `/.` so both the first and second would fail if you used `mv` because you can't move (or modify in most ways) the directory `.`.  The first does not give this error, because the `-a` option to `cp` tells it to recursively copy, so it doesn't try to modify the directory, just copy what is in it.

If you want to move a directory, don't include the trailing `/`.

You can easily move the contents of a directory without `*` -- just list every filename.   Of course, as the shell expands `*` to every filename anyway, this would be the same thing, so I'm not sure what the point is of avoiding `*`.

You could also use filename completion to expand the filenames on the command line -- in bash, one way to do that would be to use <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd>

Comment: Though using `*` is problematic in that it doesn't usually include dotfiles by default. And the workarounds are hairy since they need to avoid `..`. In Bash, you could use `shopt -s dotglob` to have it include dotfiles (other than `.` and `..`) in `*` (but `.*` would still include the two).

Comment: `foo/` isn't the same as `foo/.` though, at least wrt. `mv`. On Linux (GNU), `mv foo/. bar` gives that "Device or resource busy", while `mv foo/ bar` works.

Comment: if foo/ works, someone is stripping the trailing slash, probably mv.  YMMV.  It will work as a target, but not a source.  And all of this is different with rsync as someone already mentioned I think.

Comment: if I try it with Perl, both `rename("foo/", "bar")` and `rename("foo", "bar")` (as given in Perl and shown by strace) give ENOTEMPTY, unless `bar` is empty, in which case it replaces `bar` with `foo`. On the other hand, `rename("foo/.", "bar")` gives EBUSY. `mv` does change the args in that `mv foo/ bar` calls `rename("foo/", "bar/foo")`.

Comment: unsurprisingly `mv foo/ bar` and `mv foo bar/` do the same thing.  `strace mv foo/ bar | grep rename` gives * `renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "foo/", AT_FDCWD, "bar", RENAME_NOREPLACE) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)` * `renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "foo/", AT_FDCWD, "bar/foo", RENAME_NOREPLACE) = 0`